# webservice response dictionary disable auto sorted by keys?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am facing issue with my webserice response. Dictionary keys are auto sorted and i want them as it is

the actual webservice response is :-

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [18] => How it works
            [22] => Benefits
            [23] => Win Free Airtime
            [7] => What can I Report?
            [10] => Our Goal
            [16] => Disclaimer
            [8] => FAQ
            [13] => Terms & Conditions
            [11] => Contact Us
            [14] => Feedback / suggestion
        )
```

and it is showing below unfortunately by auto sorting

```
data =     {
        10 = "Our Goal";
        11 = "Contact Us";
        13 = "Terms & Conditions";
        14 = "Feedback / suggestion";
        16 = Disclaimer;
        18 = "How it works";
        22 = Benefits;
        23 = "Win Free Airtime";
        7 = "What can I Report?";
        8 = FAQ;
    };
```

I am stuck :( below is my code

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {


         [spinner stopAnimating];
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
         {
             //NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSDictionary * Dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
             NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *decryptedStr = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:newStr options:0];

NSDictionary * Dict  =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:decryptedStr options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, because the result is not an array but a dictionary which does not have an order.

You will have to write your own JSON parser and use something else than an `NSDictionary` to keep the order.

The best way is to change the JSON output use an array:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "key": 10,
            "value": "Our Goal"
        },
        {
            "key": 11,
            "value": "Contact Us"
        },
        {
            "key": 13,
            "value": "Terms & Conditions"
        },
        {
            "key": 14,
            "value": "Feedback / suggestion"
        },
        {
            "key": 16,
            "value": "Disclaimer"
        },
        {
            "key": 18,
            "value": "How it works"
        },
        {
            "key": 22,
            "value": "Benefits"
        },
        {
            "key": 23,
            "value": "Win Free Airtime"
        },
        {
            "key": 7,
            "value": "What can I Report?"
        },
        {
            "key": 8,
            "value": "FAQ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: there should be a way as i read nsorder set . can we do json decode to nsorderset? any help?

Comment: No, the JSON decoder is as is, since a key,value pair does not specifies any order. I would say that the design of your JSON API is not correct.

Comment: i am using NSDictionary * Dict  =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:decryptedStr options:kNilOptions error:nil];
 is it not correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but as I stated in my answer `NSDictionary` does have any ordering. Only `NSArray` has an order, thus only JSON arrays will have an order. Key-value pairs as used by your API will not have an order when parsed.

Comment: There is none, you will need to write your own JSON parser or change the output of your JSON webservice to use an array with objects.